# How to get the Json object when typeahead item is selected when using different displayKey?

Tags: javascript, html, json, typeahead

my Json object looks like

```
[{
    "subject": "search",
    "discussionURL": "www.google.com",
}]
```

I am using "subject" as displayKey in typeahead. using custom template for displaying all the fields in json object. But in

```
$('input').on([
                    'typeahead:initialized',
                    'typeahead:initialized:err',
                    'typeahead:selected',
                    'typeahead:autocompleted',
                    'typeahead:opened',
                    'typeahead:closed'
                ].join(' '), function(x) {}]);
```

I get the subject value only but i need the whole json object here. How can i get the whole json object?

Answer (score 0):

Ok i got my answer `typeahead:selected` gives the `suggestionObject` as argument

```
$('input').on([
                    'typeahead:initialized',
                    'typeahead:initialized:err',
                    'typeahead:selected',
                    'typeahead:autocompleted',
                    'typeahead:opened',
                    'typeahead:closed'
                ].join(' '), function(x,suggestionObject) {}]);
```